# iPhone call another class's selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to objective c (moving from .NET developing to iPhone). Well Now I have a simple question for someone who is experienced in iPhone development. 
I'm writing a static library which reacts on some audio events using audiotoolbox. My header looks like:

```
@interface ccreaderlib : NSObject {
    id __unsafe_unretained delegate;
    SEL _DevicePluggedEvent;
    SEL _DeviceUnpluggedEvent;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL onDevicePlugged;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL onDeviceUnplugged;


- (id)init;
- (void)startMonitor;
- (void)stopMonitor;


@end
```

now in UIViewController I'm doing this:

```
_lib = [[ccreaderlib alloc] init];
    _lib.delegate = self;
    _lib.onDevicePlugged = @selector(OnDevicePluggedIn);
    _lib.onDeviceUnplugged = @selector(OnDeviceUnplugged);
[_lib startMonitor];
```

My idea is to call UIViewController's selectors from my static library. How can I do this. At the moment I'm trying to do this in this way:

```
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
                                       void                      *inUserData,
                                       AudioSessionPropertyID    inPropertyID,
                                       UInt32                    inPropertyValueSize,
                                       const void                *inPropertyValue) 
{
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = inPropertyValue;
CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef =
CFDictionaryGetValue ( routeChangeDictionary, CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason));
SInt32 routeChangeReason;
CFNumberGetValue (
                  routeChangeReasonRef,
                  kCFNumberSInt32Type,
                  &routeChangeReason);

CFStringRef oldRouteRef =
CFDictionaryGetValue (
                      routeChangeDictionary,
                      CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_OldRoute));
NSString *oldRouteString = (__bridge NSString *)oldRouteRef;
ccreaderlib *self = (__bridge id)inUserData;
id reactClass = [self delegate];
if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_NewDeviceAvailable)
{
    if ([oldRouteString isEqualToString:@"Speaker"])
    {
        [reactClass performSelector:@selector(onDevicePlugged)];
        self.bIsReaderPlugged = YES;
    }


}
if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {
    if ([oldRouteString isEqualToString:@"Headphone"]){
        [reactClass performSelector:@selector(onDeviceUnplugged)];
        self.bIsReaderPlugged = NO;
    }
}
```

}

but in this way I get SIGABRT. Please help me,spent 3 days already trying to solve this.

***UPDATE:
Found answer myself. Changed my c callback function to look this way:

```
if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_NewDeviceAvailable)
{
    if ([oldRouteString isEqualToString:@"Speaker"])
    {
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:self.onDevicePlugged])
            [self.delegate performSelector:self.onDevicePlugged];
        self.bIsReaderPlugged = YES;
    }


}
if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {
    if ([oldRouteString isEqualToString:@"Headphone"]){
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:self.onDeviceUnplugged])
            [self.delegate performSelector:self.onDeviceUnplugged];
        self.bIsReaderPlugged = NO;
    }
}
```

thanks to http://brandontreb.com/objective-c-programming-tutorial-creating-a-twitter-client-part-1/

Comment: Maybe you should do [reactClass performSelector:@selector(_DevicePluggedEvent)]; instead of [reactClass performSelector:@selector(onDevicePlugged)];?

Comment: or even [reactClass _DevicePluggedEvent];?

Comment: This is where delegation or block-based design are useful.

Comment: That works, but is a very atypical pattern for delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you got the spelling correct - in one case it appears capitalized in the other not (first 'o').

What you should do in the class, at the very start, is verify the delegate does in fact repond to the selector:

```
BOOL [delegate repondsToSelector:your_selector_variable];
BOOL [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(TheActualSelector)]; // don't forget trailing ':' if it takes an arg
```

I would assert on these during development, as no reason to proceed if you have not gotten this correct,

Comment: well, capitalized selectors are from UIViewController class, others are properties of my ccreaderlib class defined in my static library.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very atypical pattern for delegation.  Typically, you would declare a protocol:

```
@protocol(DevicePlugDelegateP)
- (void)pluggedInDevice:(Device*)aDevice;
- (void)unpluggedDevice:(Device*)aDevice;
@end
```

Then declare your delegate like:

```
__weak NSObject<DevicePlugDelegateP>* delegate;
```

Then check for selector response and call it, if present:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pluggedInDevice:)])
    [delegate pluggedInDevice:aDevice];
```

... etc ...

Not that what you are doing is wrong, just atypical.   The above pattern makes it abundantly clear what classes can act as that particular delegate and one method implementation search later reveals who implements which methods.

Comment: I would just add that if you use a protocol, you should then in your initWithDelegate method check that in fact the delegate DOES implement the protocol [delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)], and if not, return nil instead of self.

Comment: David -- that is a good idea on the face of it, but may have consequences.  And it doesn't add any significant amount of defense as delegate methods should generally all be @optional anyway. And it can break stuff due to history.  Before we added `@optional` to protocol definitions, delegate "protocols" were declared as implementation-less categories on some random class.  Thus, you had to always check for respondsToSelector:.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that if the one say really really important delegate method is not implemented, then returning nil not self lets the user of this library that something is really wrong early on.